# Right UIBarButtonItem shows a vertical line on navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I have build an application which uses the WebView.When application launch and comes to WebView controller then before WebView complete its loading the ui bar button item shows only the custom icon but when WebView complete its loading then a vertical line show on the right side of custom icon.
This happen only on iPad Air 2 version 10.3.2 or below this version.
Here are the screen shots
before WebView completes its loading

[image]

And after complete its loading

[image: the orange indicate the vertical line]

Comment: Just check that `Title` of your `UIBarButton` is empty. I had have the similar problem for iOS 10.X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered a similar behaviour in iOS 10.X and spent some time to find a reason of the problem. So I have decided to describe it in more details.

Sometimes we can unexpectedly discover a vertical line at right side of `UIBarButtonItem` in our applications. This vertical line don’t visible in Storyboard or in iOS 11+, but it may appear unexpectedly in iOS 10.X, e.g. when `UIAlertController` was displayed.

[image: UIBarButton with line]

The  reason is that `Title` field of  `UIBarButtonItem` has "Item" value by default. I don’t know as you, but I sometimes forgot to clear this field ( not now, of course ;)) So, if you don’t want to see your `UIBarButtonItem` with title and you don’t want to see the unexpected appearance of vertical line at the right side of your button, keep `Title` field is empty.

[image: Bar Button Inspector]

Comment: Save my day. Thanks